# R plotDomain(), plotPoints()

Tags: r, plot

The code then shows the plotDomain methods for different resolutions.
Code of any resolution separately.
Question: How to plot all resolutions so that they are all visible on one graph

Packages: any from CRAN (but without having to install additional things, e.g. Java or Python)

Code:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(R6)
library(hexbin)

Domain <- R6Class(
  "Domain",
  public = list(
    data = NULL,
    resolution = NULL,
    
    initialize = function(data, resolution) {
      self$data <- data
      self$resolution <- resolution
    },
    
    plotDomain = function(resolutionIndex, border = rgb(0, 1, 1, .3), col = "#9ecae1", alpha = 0.01) {
      x <- self$data$x
      y <- self$data$y
      
      # Utworzenie mapy heksagonalnej
      hex <- hexbin(x, y, xbins = self$resolution[resolutionIndex])
      
      # Ustawienie parametrów dla linii
      par(lwd = 1.5, lend = 2)
      
      # Wyświetlenie mapy z przeźroczystym kolorem
      plot(hex, colramp = colorRampPalette(rgb(t(col2rgb(col)/255), alpha = 0.05)), 
           border = border, legend = FALSE)
    }
  )
)

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/jerzy/OneDrive/Dokumenty/R Studio/test_data_00.csv") 
#data <- read.csv(file = "./test_data_00.csv")

# Przygotowanie danych x i y
x <- data$x
y <- data$y

# Inicjalizacja obiektu klasy Domain
a <- Domain$new(data.frame(x = x, y = y), c(10, 20, 30))

graphics.off()

# Wywołanie metody plotDomain dla różnych rozdzielczości
a$plotDomain(resolutionIndex = 1)
a$plotDomain(resolutionIndex = 2)
a$plotDomain(resolutionIndex = 3)
```

My result:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you should be able to pass a `newpage` argument through to the `plot` method for hexbin, but this doesn't seem to work here. An alternative is to specify `add = TRUE` to add the hexagons to an existing plot, though this means you need to calculate and draw the hexagons in base R:

```r
Domain <- R6Class("Domain",
  public = list(
    data = NULL,
    resolution = NULL,
    initialize = function(data, resolution) {
      self$data <- data
      self$resolution <- resolution
    },
    
    plotDomain = function(resolutionIndex, border = rgb(0, 1, 1, .3), 
                          col = "#9ecae1", alpha = 0.2, add = FALSE) {
      x <- self$data$x
      y <- self$data$y
      hex <- hexbin(x, y, xbins = self$resolution[resolutionIndex])
      center_coords <- hcell2xy(hex)
      grid <- hexcoords(diff(hex@xbnds)/hex@xbins/2,
                        min(diff(sort(unique(hcell2xy(hex)$y))))/3)
                        
      polys <- Map(function(x, y, i) {
        data.frame(x = x + c(grid$x, grid$x[1]),
                   y = y + c(grid$y, grid$y[1]))
        }, center_coords$x, center_coords$y, seq_along(center_coords$x))
      
      if(add == FALSE) plot(center_coords, type = "n", xlim = hex@xbnds,
                            ylim = hex@ybnds)
      
      for(i in seq_along(polys)) {
        polygon(polys[[i]]$x, polys[[i]]$y, col = scales::alpha(col, alpha),
                border = border, lwd = 1.5)
      }
    }
  )
)
```

You haven't included any data, but it seems any bunch of x, y co-ordinates should suffice for a demo:

```
set.seed(1)

a <- Domain$new(data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000)), c(10, 20, 30))

a$plotDomain(resolutionIndex = 1)
a$plotDomain(resolutionIndex = 2, col = "gold", border = rgb(1, 1, 0, .3),
             add = TRUE)
a$plotDomain(resolutionIndex = 3, col = "tomato", border = rgb(1, 0, 0, .3),
             add = TRUE)
```

[image]